# Not able to extract value from URL using regular expression extractor

Tags: regex, jmeter

Not able to extract value for URL using regular expression extractor

I have to extract value from URL which is dynamic and then have to use it in the subsequent URLs

It is giving error as:

```
Java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 67: http://xxxx-xx.xxxx.co.in/events/3800/test_papers/${testPaperID}/submit
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$from .checkChars(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(Unknown Source)
```

I have written regular expression extractor to get the value of ${testPaperID}

In http request I have specified path as

```
/events/3800/test_papers/${testPaperID}/submit
```

But value is not being replaced in URL

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your regular expression? And a screenshot of where you are hoping to extract the URL out of?

Comment: If this is happening, this means the value is not being set, which means your regex is probably wrong.